# What is the icon on Ash Ketchum's hat?

Tags: pokemon, ash-ketchum

Throughout the *[Pokémon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon)* series, or at least the first ones, **[Ash Ketchum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_Ketchum)** wears a pretty iconic hat:

[image: Image of Ash Ketchum from the Pokémon series wearing his iconic hat]

<sup>[img src](https://www.copthesekicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/hqdefault-32-e1468358059298.jpg)</sup>

I've read [on Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_hat#Pok.C3.A9mon_League_Expo_hat) that the logo is a "stylised 'L'", however I feel like it may have a deeper meaning.

**What does the icon on Ash Ketchum's (first) hat mean?**

Comment: You might want to ask in Japanese:SE chat what the writing on the bottom right means; http://i.stack.imgur.com/SO5FS.jpg. I could decipher the word "Balance" AND "Hat" but that's about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per the [Pokémon wiki](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_hat)

> Ash's first hat, worn during the original series, is easily the most
>   well-known: **an official Pokémon League Expo hat that was red and white
>   with a green, stylized "L" on the front,** which Ash claimed to have
>   "sent in about a million postcards" in order to obtain. Misty seems to
>   have tried to win it as well, as she stated she sent in one postcard.
>   Ash wore this hat during his journey through Kanto, the Orange
>   Archipelago, and Johto, and was very attached to it, becoming enraged
>   when a Mankey stole it and played keep-away with it in Primeape Goes
>   Bananas. The design may be loosely based on Red's Generation I hat,
>   and in early concept sketches for the anime, Ash's hat matched Red's
>   exactly.

---

From [Primeape Goes Bananas](https://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/IL025:_Primeape_Goes_Bananas) (25th episode of the first season)

> **Misty:** *I didn't know **that was an official expo hat.** I remember entering the same contest myself.*
>
> **Ash:** *I had to send in a million postcards to win that hat!*
>
> **Misty:** *He he. No wonder I didn't win, I only sent in one.*

Interestingly, the hat went through several iterations before the concept artists finally settled on the "L" symbol. Unfortunately, my Japanese is insufficient to decipher the text on the right hand side at the bottom.

[image: several sketches of Ash's hat]